# Obtaining a recursion relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, power-series

I have obtained an equation using the power series solution method. For the sake of simplicity, I have substituted the complicated constants by A,B,C,... So the general form of my equation is
$$
A\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\,x^{i+3}-\sum_{i=0}^n\,[B-(i+1)]a_i\,x^{i+1}-\sum_{i=0}^na_i\,x^i-\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i(i+2)}{C}\,a_i\,x^{i-1}=0
$$
How should I proceed to get an equation including the same powers? and then get recursion relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from what you wrote 
$$A\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\,x^{i+3}-\sum_{i=0}^n\,[B-(i+1)]a_i\,x^{i+1}-\sum_{i=0}^na_i\,x^i-\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i(i+2)}{C}\,a_i\,x^{i-1}=0$$ consider what it will be for the term $x^k$ (that is to say that in each sum you fix the index $i$ such that the exponent of $x$ is $k$). Doing it,
$$A a_{k-3}-[B-k]a_{k-1}-a_k-\frac{(k+1)(k+3)}{C}\,a_{k+1}=0$$

Comment: Thanks. By doing so, do not the limits of summations change?

Comment: @Wisdom. We do not care about the summation; we just look for a single power $k$ of $x$. Take the first term :$i+3=k \implies i=k-3$; for the second $i+1=k \implies i=k-1$; for the third, no problem $i=k$; for the last $i-1=k \implies i=k+1$. Is it clear ? Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean that the limits of summations do not change? or they change, but no matter?

Comment: @Wisdom. It does not matter since we look for a single specific term

Comment: yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can write
\begin{multline*}
0 = A\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^{i+3}-\sum_{i=0}^n[B-(i+1)]a_ix^{i+1}-\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i-\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i(i+2)}{C}a_ix^{i-1} \\
= A\sum_{i=3}^{n+3} a_{i-3}x^{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}[B-i]a_{i-1}x^{i}-\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i-\sum_{i=-1}^{n-1}\frac{(i+1)(i+3)}{C}a_{i+1}x^{i}.
\end{multline*}
What is the coefficient of $x^i$ on the right-hand side? (Perhaps restrict to $3\le i\le n-1$ at first.) What is the coefficient of $x^i$ on the left-hand side?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the limits of summations are not the same in RHS, so how can we obtain the recursion relations? I thought that pulling out the first terms of each summation to reach to max power must be the correct way. Please explain more